# Using OnLongTouch to move image to string

Tags: java, android, handler

I'm trying to use this code to set an "ontouchlistener".  It says there are no errors in the code but when I try to run it I get a force quit... what is going wrong?  any ideas?

```
final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
Runnable mLongPressed = new Runnable() { 
   public void run() { 
 }   
 };

 @Override
 public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, View v){
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        handler.postDelayed(mLongPressed, 1000);
    if((event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)||(event.getAction() ==               
  MotionEvent.ACTION_UP))
    handler.removeCallbacks(mLongPressed);
    return false;    
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [`OnTouchListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) the event function is:

```
public abstract boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent event)
```

which is called when a touch event is dispatched to a view. But you are using this one?:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, View v)
```

To implement the listener, we can easily do this:

```
   myImgView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
    {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
             // put your code here
            return false;
        }
   });
```

Comment: I've been looking for how to do this and this is the only resource I could find.  I saw that abstract should be used, but for some reason it wasn't working.  Where exactly is the correct place to put my new intent.  I want "String mString = mImage.toString()"  Thanks for the help :D

Comment: Also, now I have a "abstract methods do not specify a body" error

Comment: See the updated answer., you need to override the function, and implement it. The error means that a function declared as `abstract` can't have code-block

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Implementing a listener goes fine.  However, when I try to implement the handler/runnable I run into errors.  Do you know what is causing this?

Comment: Are you trying to declare it inside the `listener`'s code ? youyr code is not giving me enough details but with some guess,  Either put it inside the event function or somewhere else which will be publicly accessible to the event function.

Comment: So, I don't want to put it inside the listener?  Because, yes, that's where I was putting it prior.

Comment: @Joseph.M, don't get me wrong, but i am guessing that you are a beginner in java. If so then please read about class, `inner class`, `abstarct class`, `interface` and `anonymous class`(for this case) . You would not understand a single thing if you don't know this basics. I think you will do better in future. :)